# Taking data in a row from and placing it into a different sheet in column form. Data is only moved if the person who has the data, name is listed

Tags: excel, vba

I have consolidated data that contains how well a person is doing at work. it has a personal email and 2 rows of data to the right. on another sheet, I created a birds-eye view of a seating chart and now I need to place the data where the person is seating (in column form like B4 and C4 for example). My data, for example, is the person's email in cell A1 and their data is in B1 and C1. Now another problem is that the actual data comes from a website so the data will be constantly updated. so that means a person data will change or will not come up at all. Although, maybe a new person might bring in data. That means a new email and new data of course.

I tried using an IF statement it that went south

```
Sub button()

     With Worksheets("three").Range("G1")

        If .Value = "sconlon@iadvancenow.com" Then

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3") = .Offset(0, 1).Value
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3") = .Offset(0, 2).Value


        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

This is what should happen at the end when everything works out. the Consolidated data will be moved to another sheet (the seating chart) and under the person's name is their data. so the data that was consolidated will be placed there. Now the data will be updated so a person's data will change and there will be people who didn't have data before will have or will not have data now.

The data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1BaN.png)

The seating chart[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHNmc.jpg)

And this is a large picture of the seating chart but this is an old one but it is similar to what I have now, but the last picture of the two names is from my actual sheet

problem im having now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsWAX.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  As is, it still sounds like a vlookup will work.

Comment: I placed a sample @tigeravatar

Comment: The images don't provide where the cells are (row/column are left out).  It also only shows a single person, so there would be no need to loop.  Lastly it doesn't show any way to look up `Sean Conlon` against the list shown in the sample data because `Sean Conlon` is not in the sample data.  If the email can be generated based off the name using a rule (like first initial + last name + @iadvancenow.com) then we can use it to perform the lookup, however it would be much easier if the data contains the name we want to look up.  Basically, there's still not enough information to effectively help.

Comment: updated question @dwirony

Comment: What do i need to add or do @tigeravatar

Comment: Add new screenshots that are more representative.  I'm certain the seating chart has more than one entry, but it's not possible to know the pattern from what you've shown.  Are all of the seats in the same column? Are there multiple seats in the same row?  A larger screenshot will be very helpful with this.  Make sure the screenshots (for both worksheets) include row/column labels so we know where the data is.  For the sample data, is there simply not a name column?  Can we actually use a rule like I described to generate an email address based off the name only?

Comment: @tigeravatar the only problem is that some of the information is confidential so I have blank out some spots

Comment: That's fine, we only need *sample* data that is representative of what you're working with, not the actual data.  Feel free to copy the layout to different sheets and replace anything confidential with fake stuff, like `name1`, `name2`, etc.

Comment: I edited it. @tigeravatar also this sheet ha to be completely automated so my boss could use it that's why I keep the emails the same. Like i said before the data will always be updated and the emails might shift in the column.

Comment: For the seating chart, are the names only on row 82?  Are the names next to each other every 3 columns as shown?  Do they start on column W?  Is the suggested rule for generating the email address from the name valid?  Do you need the result from column `H` of your data sheet one row below the name, and the result from column `I` two rows below the name?

Comment: @tigeravatar the large seating chart I showed you is from an old file but on my actual seating chart it in rows 25, 44, 65, 82, 101, 120, 139. and the columns are merged so it is BC, EF, IJ, PQ, ST, WX, ZAA and the results from column H should be 14 cells below the first name and I would be 15 cells so Sean Conlon has row 82, so results from H should be in 96 and I in 97

Comment: so the names are on the rows listed and the columns given @tigeravatar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Worksheets("three")
    Set wsDest = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim aSeatingRows As Variant
    aSeatingRows = Array(25, 44, 65, 82, 101, 120, 139)

    Dim aSeatingCols As Variant
    aSeatingCols = Array("B", "E", "I", "P", "S", "W", "Z")

    Dim vResult As Variant
    Dim sEmail As String
    Dim vRow As Variant
    Dim vCol As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    For Each vRow In aSeatingRows
        For Each vCol In aSeatingCols
            sEmail = Application.Trim(wsDest.Cells(vRow, vCol).Value)
            If Len(sEmail) > 0 Then
                sEmail = Left(sEmail, 1) & Split(sEmail, " ")(1) & "@iadvancenow.com"
                For i = 2 To 3
                    vResult = Application.VLookup(sEmail, wsData.Range("G:I"), i, False)
                    If IsError(vResult) Then
                        wsDest.Cells(vRow + i + 12, vCol).ClearContents
                    Else
                        wsDest.Cells(vRow + i + 12, vCol).Value = vResult
                    End If
                Next i
            Else
                wsDest.Cells(vRow + 14, vCol).Resize(2).ClearContents
            End If
        Next vCol
    Next vRow

End Sub
```

Comment: @tirgeravatar is their anything I need to change

Comment: @OmarAljonubi Only if your data isn't setup as you've described, or if we can't generate the email based off the name as suggested, or the sheetnames need to be changed.  I've tried to make it as easy as possible to modify.  Does it not return the expected results properly?

Comment: No, it's not working, but I don't understand what you mean by the name suggestion. Also, Sheet2 is not the actual place I need it to be sheet is called "two" but I only made a new sheet because if it works there then I will change the sheet name my self @tigeravatar

Comment: And I would like to tell you now thank you for the help you have been giving me so far, and I hope we could figure this out @tigeravatar

Comment: @OmarAljonubi On your seating chart, you only have a name, like `Sean Conlon`, but in your data table, you only have an email address, like `sconlon@iadvancenow.com`.  That means we have to generate the email address based on the name.  I have been asking if we could use a standard rule to do so, which is `first letter of first name + last name + @iadvancenow.com`.  If that rule doesn't generate the correct email address, the code will not provide correct results.  Is there somewhere on the seating chart that has the actual email address we can use?  Or can you put the name in your data table?

Comment: I will put the email in the seating Chart @tigeravatar

Comment: @OmarAljonubi where will the email address be located? One row below the name?

Comment: /Users/pricewinner/Desktop/Screen Shot 2019-06-05 at 2.57.06 PM.png

Comment: sEmail = Application.Trim(wsDest.Cells(vRow, vCol).Value)
            If Len(sEmail) > 0 Then
                sEmail = Left(sEmail, 1) & Split(sEmail, " ")(1) & "@iadvancenow.com"
                For i = 2 To 3
                    vResult = Application.VLookup(sEmail, wsData.Range("G:I"), i, False)

Comment: The sEmail...."iadvancenow.com" has a bug in ti @tigeravatar

Comment: I will replace the name of the person with their email and add a row above the email for the name

Comment: @OmarAljonubi If you are trying to add an image, please edit your question and put the image there, comments can't have images uploaded to them.  The purpose of the lines of code you've quoted is to generate the email address off of a name in the format of `firstname lastname`.  Because you're replacing that with the email address, there's no need to do additional processing.  You can simply delete that line.

Comment: @OmarAljonubi If adding the row above the email changes the rows where the email addresses are located on the Seating Chart sheet, be sure to update the row numbers in the `aSeatingRows` array.

Comment: I'm running into another problem @tigeravatar I posted it on my question

Comment: It worked well for some people but not every one

Comment: @OmarAljonubi You've posted a screenshot of a line of code that's highlighted, which probably means you got an error.  If you hover over the each variable, it show show their values.  Make sure each variable has a value.  My guess is that it's a problem due to merged cells.  My first suggestion is to never, ever used merged cells.  They're always unnecessary.  If you really need the effect, instead use [Center Across Selection](https://exceljet.net/lessons/how-to-use-center-across-selection-in-excel).

Comment: @OmarAljonubi I'm also guessing you didn't actually update the row values in the `aSeatingRows` array.  You likely added rows to include the email addresses which changed which rows the code should be looking at.  You need to update that array so that it has the new, correct values.

Comment: I have only replaced the name with the email. I have not added any rows yet

Comment: Never Mind Bro It worked perfectly thank you very much for you help @tigeravatar